# Вывод даты в нужном формате

Tags: php, дата, mysql

Уже имеется дата в формате

```
2014-06-26 12:45:10
```

Как сделать следующее. Если опубликовано сегодня, 5 минут назад то выводить:

> Сегодня | 5 минут назад,

Если прошел, например, 1 час выводить:

> Сегодня | 16:10

Если вчера, то вчера:

> Вчера | 16:10

Если в этом году:

> 26 июня | 16:10

Если не в этом году, то:

> 26 июня 2014 | 16:10

Comment: с базы данных MySQL беру дату публикации новости $row["datetime"]
как мне преобразовать в нужной формат? что то не могу понять..

<div class="datetime">'.$row["datetime"].'</div>

Answer (score 2):

Если очень грубо

```
function formatDate($date)
{
    $date = new DateTime($date);
    $now = new DateTime;
    $diff = $now - $date; // вернется объект DateInterval
    if ($diff->y > 0) {
        //выводим полную дату
    } else if ($diff->m > 0 || $diff->d > 2) {
        // выводим дату за текущий год
    } else if ($diff->d === 1) {
        // вчера
    } else if ($diff->h > 1) {
        // сегодня
    } else {
        // минут назад
    }
}
```

*Обновление*

[[@Titan93](/users/20126/titan93)](/users/20126/titan93), методом `format()` или функцией `date()`

```
$date = new DateTime($row['datetime']);
echo $date->format('d M Y | H:i');
```

Про форматы подробнее [тут](http://www.php.net//manual/ru/function.date.php).

Comment: Обновил ответ

Comment: что то не работает

Answer (score 0):

Используйте библиотеку [`MomentJS`](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: метки: php, mysql

Answer (score 0):

```
/* *** Показывает сколько прошло времени от заданного значения $a ***
 Если прошло 0...55 минут: X минут назад,
 Если сегодня: Сегодня в 17:40,
 Если вчера: Вчера в 17:40,
 Если этот год: 17:40 21/04,
 Если прошлый и менее год: 17:40 21/04/2014,
*/
function passed_time($a){
 $time = time();
 $tm = date('H:i', $a);
 $d = date('d', $a);
 $m = date('m', $a);
 $y = date('Y', $a);
 $last = round(($time - $a)/60);
 if( $last < 55 ) return "$last минут назад";
 elseif($d.$m.$y == date('dmY',$time)) return "Сегодня в $tm";
 elseif($d.$m.$y == date('dmY', strtotime('-1 day'))) return "Вчера в $tm";
 elseif($y == date('Y',$time)) return "$tm $d/$m";
 else return "$tm $d/$m/$y";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Я вот такое себе писал:

```
public static function cuteDate($date)
  {
    $today = date('d.m.Y', time());
    $yesterday = date('d.m.Y', time() - 86400);
    $dbDate = date('d.m.Y', strtotime($date));
    $dbTime = date('H:i', strtotime($date));
    switch ($dbDate)
    {
      case $today : $output = 'Сегодня в '. $dbTime; break;
      case $yesterday : $output = 'Вчера в '. $dbTime; break;
      default : $output = $dbDate;
    }
    return $output;
  }
```

Просто передаете дату и получаете вид:

> Сегодня в 16:30
>
> Вчера в 12:08